# Passing Variables in a URL to a Laravel Route

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I want to receive a GET request like this:

> people.php?name=Joe&age=24

For that, I have defined the following route:

```
Route::get('people.php?name={username}&age={id}', array(
    'as' => 'people/username/age',
    'uses' => 'ExtraController@xfunction',
));
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

How can I define this route?

Comment: You can do example.com/{name}/{age} in your route if that is what you want? So you'll have an url like domain.com/Joe/24

Comment: We want to make an ajax get call, and it seems ajax GET works this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel does not support query string routing.

Create a regular route, then pull the query string arguments from the `Input` facade:

```php
Route::get('people.php', array(
    'as' => 'people/username/age',
    'uses' => 'ExtraController@xfunction',
));
```

```php
public function xfunction()
{
    $username = Input::get('name');
    $age      = Input::get('age');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what Joseph said above. But I want to add a note that all queries should always be handled in a controller method. I'm sure you know, but best practice is obviously to never include any logic outside of routes.

Rather than queries, you can also use optional variables too with Laravel.

So rather than /test/?name=Jonathan, you can use /test/{name?} and you can then view it as /test/ or /test/Jonathan, but in the controller method, you must use

`public function ( $name = null; ) 
 { 
     dd($name); 
 }`

Comment: I use /test/{names?} laravel approach. But I needed this query way for an ajax .get function.

Comment: You could still dynamically change the URL for AJAX get so you have the root url, then just use `+query` or something and have `var query = 'something';` before. But at the end of the day, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I got it. I didn't know this was possible.